# Highcharts column chart with data from mongodb

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have tried to create a column chart using highcharts in nodejs and data is getting fetched from mongodb.
I am getting stuck in series option Please help me to get out of it.

The below is my code for ejs file -

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Pie Highcharts Example</title>


    <!--  Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/highcharts.js"></script>


    <!-- Optional: the exporting module -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/exporting.js"></script>


    <!--  Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
         chartdata= <%-JSON.stringify(data)%>

        var category = [];
        var dname=[];
        var kdata=[];
        for(j=0;j<chartdata.length;j++){
            category[j]=[chartdata[j].catname]
            // name[j]=[chartdata[j].seriesname]
            // data[j]=[chartdata[j].wdata,chartdata[j].hdata,chartdata[j].cdata]
        }
        for(k=0;k<chartdata.length;k++){
            dname[k]=[chartdata[k].seriesname];
        }
        for(i=0;i<chartdata.length;i++){
             kdata[i] = [chartdata[i].wordval,chartdata[i].codeval,chartdata[i].highval];

        }
        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average data'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    categories: category
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 0,
                    y: 40,
                    floating: true,
                    shadow: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return ''+
                            this.series.name +': '+ this.y ;
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.3,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: dname[0],
                    data: kdata[0]

                },
                {
                    name: dname[1],
                    data: kdata[1]

                },
                {
                    name: dname[2],
                    data: kdata[2]

                }
                ]
            });


        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Add the container -->
    <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

@NishithChaturvedi - When I am doing this way its working so only the problem with loop I know I am asking silly question but didn't able to rectify.

Comment: Just tell what is the problem you are facing.. can you able to get the chart or atlease a plot.. or create a jsfiddle

Comment: put your json response here

Comment: series: [name,data  ] isn't right.there should not be a series of names and then a series of data. Instead there should be  { name : 'theName',
                data :  yourData                   }  in loop.

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi : I tried that series : {name: name, data:data } but then also it is not showing the chart.

Comment: not this way , while iterating your json you should fill the object and then use in chart.Can you put your json response here so that I can be able to create a working fiddle for you?

Comment: [{
    "_id": 1,
    "catname": "wordpress",
    "month": "jan",
    "wordpress": 5,
    "code": 4,
    "highcharts": 6
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "catname": "code",
    "month": "feb",
    "wordpress": 7,
    "code": 3,
    "highcharts": 5
},
{
    "_id": 3,
    "catname": "highcharts",
    "month": "march",
    "wordpress": 7,
    "code": 3,
    "highcharts": 5
}
]

Comment: will create a fiddle and share in few minutes :)

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi : Thnk u  :)

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi - Thanx for giving your time but I fixed It.

Comment: Nice to hear that!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time I have fixed the problem I was facing in series value
I just created another array var and store the name and data to it and pass that array in series.